# ionic angular app manage login and logout pages acces

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i have ionic app with side menus having home , login , dashboard, logout(items).

I am using server api to login user , i want when used is logged in side menu items login to be not there and dashboard, logout to be added , same way when user logouts he can see login but not logout and dashboard menu .

Ionic angular is bit new for me, can u please tell me login how to manage these i think session like thing may not work .

Please guide me way to do this

Answer (score 0):

In your controler need to create a var $scope.show-menu = false when you logged set to true, in you menu template use bg-hide

```
     <div  ng-hide ="show_menu">
      <ion-item menu-close class="item-icon-left"  ng-click="logOut()">
          <i class="icon ion-lock-combination" ></i>
          Log in Form
      </ion-item>
     </div>

      <div  ng-show ="show_menu">
      <ion-item menu-close class="item-icon-left"  ng-click="logOut()">
          <i class="icon ion-ios-home-outline" ></i>
          Log Out
      </ion-item>
     </div>

      <div  ng-show ="show_menu">
          <ion-item menu-close class="item-icon-left" href="#/app/mainMenuForm">
              <i class=" icon ion-ios-list-outline"></i>
              menu option a
          </ion-item>
      </div>
```

Comment: check did u way u said : http://codepen.io/gauravcoder/pen/bEjGNa seems not working